# Can't call base class's method when another overload present in derived class

Tags: c++

I get a compiler error "function does not take 0 arguments" when compiling the following code.

```
class A
{
public:
    int Foo()
    {
        return 1;
    }

protected:
    virtual void Foo(int& n)
    {
        n += 1;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    // Override of A
    void Foo(int& n)
    {
        n += 2;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    B b;
    int n = b.Foo();
    return n;
}
```

It looks like the compiler insists on calling overload B::Foo(int&) instead of A::Foo().  I must be missing something obvious here.  Any pointers to C++ standard that explain the compiler's behaviour will be appreciated.

I do realise that "int n = ((A)b).Foo();" will make the compiler happy but this is not an ideal solution for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line:

```
using A::Foo;
```

in class `B` (public part) and it will work.

In this case `Foo` from `B` *hides* `Foo` from `A`. One of the C++ strange behaviors.

Comment: It is strange indeed - or at least not intuitive.  Thanks.

Comment: @bdristan The concept here is that functions from different namespaces don't overload. If you want `A::Foo()` to be an overload for `B::Foo()`, it needs to also live in `B`